# Forwarding all my mails to another mail server?

Tags: email

I have a domain where I'm not able to create an email inbox. It's possible that i can configure my mx records to forward all mails from "name@mydomain.com" to "inbox@anotherdomain.com" ?

The problem is that I've registerd on a service with an mail address, transfered the domain to another provider without the possibility to create mail inboxes and now I can't access to the specified inbox...

Comment: What MTA are you using?

Comment: It would be helpful to list which services you're using.

Comment: I think I can't answer it directly. My domain is hosted at https://www.df.eu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MX record are use to direct all emails for a domain to specific mail servers.

So you have to configure a mail server (with a fixed public IP address) to accept emails for your domain, configure the inbox(es) you need on this server and change your MX record to point to this server.

... or change again your domain to a provider that provide those facilities.

Comment: I thought the afford is too high... I think I will have to change my contract, that I'm able to create mail inboxes. Thank you very much!